# Capitalizing first letter of input in Redux fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, capitalization

I'm trying to capitalize the first letter of the input of my redux field. This is my code

```
const renderField = ({input, className, label, type, meta: {error, touched, submitFailed}}) => {

  return (<div>
    <div>
      <input {...input}
             className={className + ' ' + classNames(submitFailed && ((error && 'empty_field empty_placeholder')))}
             placeholder={label} id={label} type={type}/>
     </div>
  </div>)

};

const SignUp = ({handleSubmit, emailSignUp, signUpStatus}) => {

  return (

       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(emailSignUp)}>
           <div className="width_100">
                <div className="float_left text_align_left landing_name_cont">
                    <Field
                      className="landing_input"
                      name="signUpFirstName"
                      type="text"
                      maxLength={5}
                      component={renderField}
                      label="First name"
                      validate={[required]}
                    />
              </div>

       </form>

  )
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signUp'
})(SignUp)
```

There are many examples to do this when there's a normal input field but lacks examples on redux fields. How can i capitalize the first letter of a redux field?

Comment: what do you mean by redux fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is manipulating the user input. You can use normalize in this situation.

There is a good example in the Redux docs: https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/normalizing/

```
const capitalize = value => value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)

<Field
    name="username"
    component="input"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Username"
    normalize={capitalize}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you.exactly what i needed